# Sqlite statement match exact string iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have the following words in table database:

```
name     id
aba       0
abac      1
abaca     2
abace     3
```

I want to make the following select:

```
Select id from words where name='abaca';
```

I tried but it doesn't work. I want the exact match of the word I'm entering to match.

Comment: Describe "doesn't work" please?

Comment: SELECT id FROM words WHERE name LIKE 'abaca'

Comment: it doesn't return anything...

Comment: SELECT id  from words where nume LIKE  'abac%' this works perfect but i only want to match 'abac'

Comment: can you help me with this pls?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your entries and following query does work perfectly fine for an Exact match

```
SELECT * FROM Match WHERE title='abaca';
```

Where Match is the table name with following schema

```
CREATE TABLE Match (title text,recordId integer)
```

Following is the record inserted

[image]

Though I made the same mistake by Taking Match as Table name as you did by taking id as the column name, but I only realized it while posting the code. But that should really not make much difference here.

Have you used it in some code to fetch result from database? in case yes you should consider avoiding KEYWORDS as variable,column names.. Just  a suggestion.

Comment: Rahul, can I ask what tool you're using to test the search there? Thanks.

Comment: My table is:CREATE TABLE "words" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "nume" VARCHAR)

Comment: Yes I am using SQLiteManager URL http://download.cnet.com/SQLiteManager/3000-2065_4-94405.html

Comment: On my table it doesn't work i don't know why. I only want to match the exact word i am giving.

Comment: should i use text in stead of varchar?

Comment: I created the database using - CREATE TABLE "words" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL , "nume" VARCHAR) and inserted values using - INSERT INTO words (nume)VALUES ('abacae') the search result - Select id from words where nume='abaca';
 return 3 as id :)

Comment: Does not seem if this is an issues with Varchar or text.. For best practice to choose the datatype you can go through the documentation at http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: don't really know why it  returns nothing .Maybe it's from the sqlite version...I have the addon   sqlite manager for mozilla.

Comment: So i didn't solve the problem.. it gives the exact same issue...Can anyone help me please?

Comment: If You can place the entire code that will work else you can send the code .. Either Email it or upload it at some place..

Comment: So i created my database:CREATE TABLE "allwords" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL , "nume" VARCHAR)

Comment: i inserted exact as in your example and it actually works...but i am reading all those words from a .txt file and inserting them in my database...so when i search for one word still gives the exact problem.

Comment: @vas88y Please edit your question and describe the steps you are doing one by one.That way we can test all the steps and find some resoultion. In case you want further help you can reach me at my mail id.